# How to add xml:lang="en" to <html> tag

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

I have an XElement object for the following xml.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<div>Hello world</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to add  xml:lang="en" to  tag. So it become

```
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I tried the following code.

```
XAttribute xmlLang = new XAttribute("xml:lang","en");
```

But I got the following error:

The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass an [XName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) instance that consists of the namespace (*http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml*) and the local name (*lang*) to the XAttribute constructor.

```
XAttribute xmlLang = new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en");
```